# How to decrease sensor sensitive level on Android, java?

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

once again I need your help guys,

I have good class `CustomSensorEventListener` (see below)

All data like azimuth, poll, pitch i get properly.

I have single image on the screen that moves according to sensor orientation.

However, the sensors are too sensitive, I mean on any nano change, my image moves slightly.

Something like trembling. How can I decrease sensor level to be like camera on Android.

As you know the camera doesn't trembles on any sensor change.

Thanks,

```
public class CustomSensorEventListener implements SensorEventListener {
float[] inR = new float[16];
float[] I = new float[16];
float[] gravity = new float[3];
float[] geomag = new float[3];
float[] orientVals = new float[3];

public static double azimuth = 0;
public static double pitch = 0;
static double roll = 0;

private Display mDisplay;

public CustomSensorEventListener(Display display){
    mDisplay = display;     
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    // If the sensor data is unreliable return
    if (sensorEvent.accuracy == SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE)
        return;

    // Gets the value of the sensor that has been changed
    switch (sensorEvent.sensor.getType()) {  
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            gravity = sensorEvent.values.clone();
            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
            geomag = sensorEvent.values.clone();
            break;
    }

    // If gravity and geomag have values then find rotation matrix
    if (gravity != null && geomag != null) {

        // checks that the rotation matrix is found
        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(inR, I,
                                                          gravity, geomag);

        float[] outR = new float[16];
        if (success) {

            SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(inR, SensorManager.AXIS_Y, SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Z, outR);

//              Display display = mContext.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
            int deviceRot = mDisplay.getRotation();

            switch (deviceRot)
            {
            // portrait - normal
            case Surface.ROTATION_0: SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(inR,
                    SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Z,
                    outR);
            break;
            // rotated left (landscape - keys to bottom)
            case Surface.ROTATION_90: SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(inR,
                    SensorManager.AXIS_Z, SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X,
                    outR); 
            break;
            // upside down
            case Surface.ROTATION_180: SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(inR,
                    SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Z,
                    outR); 
            break;
            // rotated right
            case Surface.ROTATION_270: SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(inR,
                    SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Z, SensorManager.AXIS_X,
                    outR); 
            break;

            default:  break;
            }



            SensorManager.getOrientation(outR, orientVals);
            azimuth = Math.toDegrees(orientVals[0]);
            pitch = Math.toDegrees(orientVals[1]);
            roll = Math.toDegrees(orientVals[2]);
        }

        //Log.v("MA","Az: "+azimuth+", Pi: "+pitch+", Ro: "+roll);
    }
}
};
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but from the code it looks like the `outR` calculated by first `remapCoordinateSystem()` is then ignored and overwritten by the following `remapCoordinateSystem()` bound to display rotation. Ok, I know I'm super late to this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a low-pass filter to filter out the jerks, vibrations, and sudden quick movements. The filter will allow slower movements like changing the rotation angle based on a specific cutoff frequency.

More information and implementation details: [Low-Pass-Filter-To-Android-Sensors](https://github.com/Bhide/Low-Pass-Filter-To-Android-Sensors)

[Smoothing Sensor Data with a Low-Pass Filter](http://blog.thomnichols.org/2011/08/smoothing-sensor-data-with-a-low-pass-filter)

More on low-pass filters(Wikipedia): [Low-pass filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter)